# Oracle UPDATE table with multi tables joined

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, dml

I'm using `Oracle SQL Developer` and have following problem. In my DB i'm able to select one specific record i want:

```
SELECT TA.name 
FROM TABLE_A TA, TABLE_B TB, TABLE_C TC, TABLE_D TD, TABLE_E TE
WHERE
TA.ref_set = TB.ref_id AND
TA.ref_grp = TC.ref_id AND
TB.ref_nick = TD.ref_parm AND
TD.ref_id = TE.ref_id AND
TE.name = 'I'
```

but when i try to change it into UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE (
SELECT TA.name 
FROM TABLE_A TA, TABLE_B TB, TABLE_C TC, TABLE_D TD, TABLE_E TE
WHERE
TA.ref_set = TB.ref_id AND
TA.ref_grp = TC.ref_id AND
TB.ref_nick = TD.ref_parm AND
TD.ref_id = TE.ref_id AND
TE.name = 'I') SET TA.name = 'new_name'
```

it returns `ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table`

I also tried MERGE statement:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_A TA USING (
SELECT TA.name
FROM TABLE_A TA, TABLE_B TB, TABLE_C TC, TABLE_D TD, TABLE_E TE
WHERE
TA.ref_set = TB.ref_id AND
TA.ref_grp = TC.ref_id AND
TB.ref_nick = TD.ref_parm AND
TD.ref_id = TE.ref_id AND
TE.name = 'I') TX ON (TX.name = TA.name)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TA.name = 'new_name'
```

but with no luck - `ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated`

Comment: Why are you trying to `select` something from a table `TABLE_A` if you can just place all that (unreadable non-ANSI) joins in the `where` clause of the `UPDATE`: by using `exists` or `in` predicate? `update table_a set name = 'new_name' where exists( select 'nothing' from TABLE_B TB, TABLE_C TC, TABLE_D TD, TABLE_E TE
WHERE
TA.ref_set = TB.ref_id AND
TA.ref_grp = TC.ref_id AND
TB.ref_nick = TD.ref_parm AND
TD.ref_id = TE.ref_id AND
TE.name = 'I')`

Comment: Your statment doesn't work if i don't add TABLE_A to FROM. Then it works but it updates all of the records in TABLE_A.

Comment: Please provide reproducible example, because it does work, see [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8sIe8AoA)

Answer (score 1):

You can't link talbe in UPDATE but you can add to the condition something that identifies the rows, for example, the ID if it exists, and update only these rows.

```
UPDATE TABLE_A TA1 SET TA1.name = 'new_name' where TA1.id in (
    SELECT TA.id 
    FROM TABLE_A TA, TABLE_B TB, TABLE_C TC, TABLE_D TD, TABLE_E TE
    WHERE
    TA.ref_set = TB.ref_id AND
    TA.ref_grp = TC.ref_id AND
    TB.ref_nick = TD.ref_parm AND
    TD.ref_id = TE.ref_id AND
    TE.name = 'I'
    )
```

Comment: The most reliable way to identify the exact row in self-join during `merge` is to use `rowid` in the `on` clause

Comment: I changed id to rowid as you suggested and it worked. but took almost a minute so there is probably more efficient way. Nevertheless rowid gets the job done!